# Self-hosting WCF in Windows Forms without another Windows process

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I have a Windows application and want to self-host a WCF in it. This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx) walks you through how to self-host WCF in a console. [Jason Henderson's article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18789/A-Quick-and-Dirty-WCF-Service-and-Client-Using-WCF) demonstrates how to call the service. But the problem is, I don't want to host my service in another Windows process. I want to host it in my client application.

Here is my workaround:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd> to run the service
2. Add service reference to my client
   application

Then I can start my service in my client like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));
    host.Open();
    Application.Run(new Form1());
    host.Close();
}
```

It works, but I wonder if there are any simpler ways to do this.

Comment: That looks pretty simple to me... what exactly do you expect us to _review_?

Comment: i'm looking for a better solution, not my ugly workaround :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also start host in another thread:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));
            host.Open();
    };
```

(or using classic Thread and ThreadStart).

Comment: You should consider marking this Task with the `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` option